# Minimap doesn't see the terrain

Tags: 3d, terrain, opengl-es2, godot-3, minimap

The minimap does follow the player movement and does everything a minimap should be able to do... except it doesn't see the land...only the sea even tho land and sea are on the same maks level

[image]

Camera set up, just a secondary camera 200 meters above the player, point straight down and attached to a viewport

The camera also as the classic camroot spatial node with a script attached to it, the minimpa rotates around the player only on the vertical axis, completely locked so the minimap rotates to adjust to the direction of the player (kind of like in the mobile game free fire or other shooter games)  and has a the basic script to make the camera follow the player

Comment: This question does not contain enough information about how you set up your minimap for a reader to be able to spot the source of the problem. Please edit your post to contain a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example: all the steps a reader would need to follow to go from a new, empty project to a working demo of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

kind of Solved kind of not solved, I wasted a good half an hour changing all the camera settings to see if it helps..

all I had to was to do was to take the entire world node (the one that governs all the terrain) and move it down below vertical coordinate 0, still the tops of mountains are invisible in orthogonal mode and so is the sea level and anything underwater

But I mean, that's ok for now I'm not gonna add anything underwater for a while now

[image]